# RavenDB 2 returns 401 when trying to create database

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

This is a fresh install of Raven #2230, running on IIS8/Win8. When studio starts it offers to create new database, then browser pops up credentials window (401).

Web.config has *add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="All"/* set. Also tried *add key="Raven/AnonymousUserAccessMode" value="All"/* as per [documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/deployment/as-iis-application).

Anonymous Authentication on site is enabled, so is Windows Authentication.

Added Raven.Bundles.Authorization.dll to plugins folder (not sure if needed, but didn't make any difference).

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

RavenDB as of today, is on version 2750 (stable). Upgrade and this issue should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to set the AnonymousAccess setting in web.config to Admin:

```
<add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="Admin"/>
```

You should change this back to All once you have created your database.